# How to execute a bash script to configure channel MQ?

Tags: bash, ibm-mq

```
#!/bin/bash
su - mqm -c " echo 'define channel(CLSTQ1.ESBQM) CHLTYPE(CLUSRCVR) TRPTYPE(TCP) CONNAME('example.corp(1414)') CLUSTER(CLSTQ1) DESCR('tcp cluster receirver channel for QM ESBQM')' | runmqsc ESBQM "
```

when i execute this script I have the following errors:

> ```
> -bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token \`('
> -bash: -c: line 0: ` echo 'define channel(CLSTQ1.ESBQM) CHLTYPE(CLUSRCVR) TRPTYPE(TCP) CONNAME('example.corp(1414)')  CLUSTER(CLSTQ1) DESCR(tcp cluster receirver channel for QM ESBQM)' | runmqsc ESBQM '
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do it this way in one line:

```
echo "define channel(CLSTQ1.ESBQM) CHLTYPE(CLUSRCVR) TRPTYPE(TCP) CONNAME('example.corp(1414)') CLUSTER(CLSTQ1) DESCR('tcp cluster receirver channel for QM ESBQM')" | su - mqm -c "runmqsc ESBQM"
```

Comment: sorry for answering late, thanks for your answer JoshMc it works fine

Answer (score 2):

That's not a good way to do it.

Do the following:

(1) Put your MQSC commands in a file.  Lets call it ***crt_chl.mqsc***

```
define channel(CLSTQ1.ESBQM) CHLTYPE(CLUSRCVR) TRPTYPE(TCP) CONNAME('example.corp(1414)') CLUSTER(CLSTQ1) DESCR('tcp cluster receirver channel for QM ESBQM')
```

(2) Issue the command as follows:

su - mqm -c "runmqsc ESBQM < crt_chl.mqsc > crt_chl.mqsc.out"

(3) Now check the bottom of the crt_chl.mqsc.out file to see if it was successful or had errors.